# All or nothing, yes or no

Tags: riddle

Here is a simple riddle for you:

I stand for nothing but I am everything, with 100%.

There are ideas wanting to replace me with something that can stand for more but can't even decide what it is.

I stand for information but I can only answer a yes/no question.

I am contained in this riddle but you cannot see me.

The romans only knew half of me but nowadays I am more important than ever.

Who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are:

> A Bit

I stand for nothing but I am everything, with 100%.

> You can be 0 or 1, nothing or everything.

There are ideas wanting to replace me with something that can stand for more but can't even decide what it is.

> Quantum computing may be the future, and literally involves uncertainty (superposition)

I stand for information but I can only answer a yes/no question.

> Bits are the basis of all info, but only have 2 states

I am contained in this riddle but you cannot see me.

> I'm reading this on a computer

The romans only knew half of me but nowadays I am more important than ever.

> Romans had a common concept of 1 but not zero

Comment: Perfect! Everything is correct.

Comment: Yes, I had two puzzels on my mind and I recently found this site.

Comment: Submitted the answer 10 seconds before I could press submit. True to your name? ;)